# Trouble hitting a container's exposed port from a seperate container & host

Tags: macos, docker, vagrant

I have two vagrant hosts running local on my machine and I am trying to hit a container within one host from a second container on the other host.

When I curl from **within the container**:

```
curl search.mydomain.localhost:9090/ping
```

I receive the curl: `(7) Failed to connect to search.mydomain.localhost port 9090: Connection refused`

However when I curl without specifying the port:

```
curl search.mydomain.localhost/ping
OK
```

I'm certain the port is properly exposed as if I try the same from **within the host** instead of within the container I get:

```
curl search.mydomain.localhost:9090/ping
OK
```

Which shows that the service at port 9090 is exposed, however there is some networking issue with the container trying to reach it.

A fellow dev running the same versions of vbox/vagrant/docker/docker-compose and using an identical commit of the repos has no trouble hitting the service from within the container. I'm really stumped as to what to try from here...

I'm using the default bridge network:

```
sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.02427c9cea3c   no      veth5dc6655
                            vethd1867df

docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "e4b8df614d4b8c451cd4a26c5dda09d22d77de934a4be457e1e93d82e5321a8b",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.1/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
            "1d67a1567ff698694b5f10ece8a62a7c2cdcfcc7fac6bc58599d5992def8df5a": {
                "EndpointID": "4ac99ce582bfad1200d59977e6127998d940a688f4aaf4f3f1c6683d61e94f48",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3e8b6cbd89507814d66a026fd9fad26d649ecf211f1ebd72ed4689b21e781e2c": {
                "EndpointID": "2776560da3848e661d919fcc24ad3ab80e00a0bf96673e9c1e0f2c1711d6c609",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm on Docker version 1.9.0, build 76d6bc9 and docker-compose version: 1.5.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue which seems like it might be a bug. Essentially the container was inheriting the /etc/hosts from my local macbook, bypassing the /etc/hosts on the actual vagrant host running the container, causing my entry of "127.0.0.1 search.mydomain.localhost" to make all connection attempts within the container redirect to itself.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the hours to find the answer!